# How is the equality operator in Pandas treated specially by Python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df [df ['Some Column'] ==5]
```

If we take a look at the conditional in this statement, we have an equality comparator between `df ['Some Column']` and `5`. Typically, this should return `False`. But with Pandas, this returns a `Series` of the dataframe. How is this magic done behind the scenes? As you would expect a Series Object is not equal to 5, returning `False`. How does Pandas or Python ensure that False is not returned?

Comment: Python allows classes to redefine how operators work with them. Pandas has overridden the `==` operator so it works row-wise and returns a series of results.

Comment: Documentation: ["'rich comparison' methods"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__). Tutorial:  [Python \_\_eq\_\_](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__eq__/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override how operators are treated by defining e.g. `__eq__` in a class. It's super easy (in principle), here's an example:

```
class MySeries:
    def __init__(self, list_obj):
        self.list_obj = list_obj
    
    def __eq__(self, value):
        return [bool(value == obj) for obj in self.list_obj]


my_ser = MySeries([1,2,3,4,5])
my_ser == 2

# output
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Via inheritence, `pandas.Series.__eq__` is:

```py
class OpsMixin:
    ...
    @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
```

```py
class Series(base.IndexOpsMixin, generic.NDFrame):
    ...
    def _cmp_method(self, other, op):
        res_name = ops.get_op_result_name(self, other)

        if isinstance(other, Series) and not self._indexed_same(other):
            raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")

        lvalues = self._values
        rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True, extract_range=True)

        with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
            res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)

        return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)
```

So when you do:

```py
pd.Series([1,2,3,4]) == 2
```

What is really returned is the result of:

```py
import operator

import numpy as np

operator.eq(np.array([1,2,3,4]), 2)
```

So maybe your question should really be how do numpy arrays check for equality?