# Python Function Arguments with Expressions

Tags: python, function, syntax, arguments, expression

I have been looking Snowpark API refrence document and saw something like that:

```
target.merge(
         source
        , (target["key"] == source["key"]) & (target["value"] == "too_old")
        , [
          when_matched().update({"value": source["value"]})
          , when_not_matched().insert({"key": source["key"]})
         ]
)
```

Second argument is an "Column" object but as you can see it is an expression. I could not understand what property of is this syntax? Is it lambda expression or what?

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/blob/release-v1.11.1/src/snowflake/snowpark/table.py#L591-L681

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Table.merge

I could not find how it is working, and seacrh  a lot of key word such as passing expression as an argument etc but could not find anything

Comment: Similar question regarding how Pandas does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73381512/how-is-the-equality-operator-in-pandas-treated-specially-by-python

Comment: Nothing special is going on here in terms of "passing an expression as an argument". The expression is evaluated before being passed, just like it is when you do `print(5+7)`. The important thing is that the library has overridden `__eq__` so that the comparisons with `==` return not True or False, but objects which the library can interpret in the way it needs to.

Comment: (Also, presumably it overrides `__and__` so that `&` combines the results of the two `==` comparisons in the appropriate way.)

Comment: These might be the relevant parts of the source code (haven't checked in detail): https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/blob/7813b7dff97bce3bfe99946bfbdb6e1f76d2cd87/src/snowflake/snowpark/column.py#L263 and https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/blob/7813b7dff97bce3bfe99946bfbdb6e1f76d2cd87/src/snowflake/snowpark/column.py#L485